# Querying with ActiveRecord Enum

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I have the following Enum in my model

```
  enum email_reminders: { disabled_reminders: 0, default_reminders: 1, friendly_reminders: 2 }
```

When I do :

```
Company.where.not(email_reminders: :disabled_reminders).to_sql
```

I get this result:

```
 => "SELECT \"companies\".* FROM \"companies\" WHERE (\"companies\".\"email_reminders\" != NULL)"
```

When I do:

```
Company.where(email_reminders: [:default_reminders, :friendly_reminders]).to_sql
```

I get

```
=> "SELECT \"companies\".* FROM \"companies\" WHERE \"companies\".\"email_reminders\" IN (NULL, NULL)"
```

According to the documentation this should work fine?  I'm using ActiveRecord 4.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have been looking at the [Rails 5 documentation for ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) while intending to use the [Rails 4.2.6 documentation for ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). In Rails 4.2.6, the docs state:

> Where conditions on an enum attribute must use the ordinal value of an enum.

and don't show any examples of what you're doing, whereas in the Rails 5 docs, that statement about requiring the ordinal value is missing and they *do* show the examples you're using.